# Dynamically populate h:SelectOneListbox

Tags: jsf, javabeans, el, jsf-1.2

Currently I'm trying to populate the `h:selectOneListbox` with values from database.

My function to fetch the data `findAllCriteria()`

```
public List<String> findAllCriteria() {
        try {
            List<Criteria> crits = criteriaFacade().findAllByAnmeldename(getCurrentUserName(),
                    getCriteriaDefinition().getName());
            List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Criteria crit : crits) {
                results.add(crit.getId().toString());
            }

            return results;
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            LOG.error("failed to load criteria" + e);
            messageFactory().makeAndAdd(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this function I'm passing to my Converter `criteriaToSelectItems(meldungListController.findAllCriteria())`

```
public static List<SelectItem> criteriaToSelectItems(List<String> elements) {
    List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(elements.size());
    for (String element : elements) {
        items.add(new SelectItem(element, element));
    }
    return items;

}
```

as defined here:

```
 <function>
<function-name>criteriaToSelectItems</function-name>
<function-class>de.db.udg.diagnose.udgdiag.webui.app.facelets.functions.SelectItemsFunctions</function-class>
<function-signature>java.util.List criteriaToSelectItems(java.util.List)</function-signature>
```

The critial part is:

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="critList" size="1"
                                value="#{meldungListController.findCriteriaById(identifier)}">
                                <f:selectItems
                                    value="#{d:criteriaToSelectItems(meldungListController.findAllCriteria())}" />
                    </h:selectOneListbox>
```

I don't understand how to retrieve the Item(`String`) from the selected Item and how to further process it.

```
 public Criteria findCriteriaById(String identifier) {
    if (identifier.isEmpty()) {
        return querySpec.getCriteria();
    }
    Long id = Long.valueOf(identifier);
    Criteria criteria;
    try {
        criteria = criteriaFacade().findById(id);
    } catch (BusinessException e) {
        LOG.error("failed to load criteria" + e);
        messageFactory().makeAndAdd(e);
        return null;
    }

    return criteria;

}
```

Both functions are nested inside of `@Component("meldungListController")`
)

I've read through [this article on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) but this is kind of limited to JSF 2.x

*Upgrading my JSF Version from 1.2 to 2.x is no option.*

### Question

How to dynamically populate selectOneListbox in JSF 1.2 and find the value of the selected index.

In-Depth:

Listing all selectItems works, see image, but:

[image: detail]

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/meldung/meldungList.xhtml @341,72 value="#{meldungListController.findCriteriaById(identifier)}": The class 'de.db.udg.diagnose.udgdiag.webui.meldung.MeldungListController' does not have the property 'findCriteriaById'.
```

I hope someone remembers the good old days with JSF 1.2 and can help me.

Comment: Creating SelectItem objects is superfluos. You can just use lists with your own objects. So the `List<String> elements`  is already enough

Comment: Oh wait, you are doing all this in JSF 1.2???? Wow... then my previous comment is invalid

Comment: findCriteria is a method (with a parameter) not a property. So it is a methodExpression and the `value` attribute requires a valueExpression...